# задача по комбинаторике

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Клара боится забыть секретную комбинацию цифр, открывающую сейф. Поэтому она решила в зашифрованном виде записать эту комбинацию в тетрадке. Для зашифровывания цифры были выписаны в таблицу, после чего Клара несколько раз наугад переставила столбцы этой таблицы, запомнив при этом способ перестановки. Затем она переставила столбцы еще раз таким же способом и записала окончательный результат в тетрадку. За какое минимальное кол=во перебора комбинаций можно открыть сейф?

```
4 5 6 2 2 0
2 9 0 1 9 9
```

Вроде решение в лоб

> p= 6! = 720 комбинаций.

Но преподаватель уверяет, что есть решение в котором число комбинаций будет заметно меньше. Путем многочисленных попыток сдать задачу, узнать в какую сторону думать, и что я делаю не так, в ответ добился только того, что значение больше 256 и меньше 360. Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: Не знаю откуда, но у меня получилось `6*5*5 + 6*5*4 + 6*5*3 + 6*5*2 + 6*5*1 = 360` :-D   хотя наверное первая комбинация будет 6.5.4... то есть итог `6*5*4 + 6*5*3 + 6*5*2 + 6*5*1 = 285`

Comment: как мне пытались объяснить, Надо вычислить квадраты всех перестановок. Квадраты лежат среди четных перестановок, значит уже не более 360.
Из этого числа надо вычесть еще число тех четных перестановок, которые не являются квадратами. Но я ничего не понял

Comment: http://oeis.org/A003483

Answer (score 2):

Две одинаковые перестановки подряд дают перестановку хитрого вида — грубо говоря, перестановку в квадрате.

Например, перестановка `1 3 2 4 5 0`. Будучи применена к самой себе, она даст перестановку `3 4 2 5 0 1`, которая представляет собой квадрат первой перестановки.

Как посчитать количество таких перестановок теоретически, не знаю, но для всего лишь 6 чисел их легко посчитать программно — возвести в квадрат все 720 перестановок и посмотреть количество уникальных.

Вот такой простенький код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> z {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    set<vector<int>> s;
    do {
        vector<int> r0 {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        vector<int> r1 (6);
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            r1[i] = r0[z[i]];
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            r0[i] = r1[z[i]];
        s.insert(r0);
    } while(next_permutation(z.begin(),z.end()));
    cout << s.size() << endl;
}
```

говорит, что таких перестановок — 270.